# Magento 2 System Configuration for Module issue

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, system.xml, acl

I visited many sites for find solution of this issue.

But after creating `system.xml` and `acl.xml` Magento give me a report generated error.

**Error**

> a:4:{i:0;s:140:"Notice: Undefined index: id in
>   /usr/local/ampps/www/mgn2/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php
>   on line 59";i:1;s:6391:"#0
>   /usr/local/ampps/www/mgn2/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php(59):
>   Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...',
>   '/usr/local/ampp...', 59, Array)

Can you clarify this issues?

**app/code/Pulsestorm/HelloWorldMVVM/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="Pulsestorm" translate="label" sortOrder="200">
            <label>Pulsestorm</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="config_helloworld" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="110" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Pulsestorm</label>
            <tab>HelloWorldMVVM</tab>
            <resource>Pulsestorm_HelloWorldMVVM::config_helloworldmvvm</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Hello World</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="block_label" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Module page title</label>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**app/code/PulseStorm/HelloWorldMVVM/etc/acl.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Magento_Backend::admin">
                <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores">
                    <resource id="Magento_Backend::stores_settings">
                        <resource id="Magento_Config::config">
                            <resource id="Pulsestorm_HelloWorldMVVM::config_helloworldmvvm" title="HelloWorldMVVM" />
                        </resource>
                    </resource>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In your `system.xml` replace this

```
<tab>HelloWorldMVVM</tab>
```

with this

```
<tab>Pulsestorm</tab>
```

Comment: @Marius: Can you share a bit context? I get the same error but I'm puzzled what to enter in my case.

Comment: you are referencing a tab that does not exist. Each `<tab>` tag has an id and this way you can add sections under certain tabs. But if you add a section under a tab that does not exist you get the error above.

Comment: @Marius: Yes, just found it myself, too. Thanks a lot. Now on to the next mystery ... :)

Comment: @Marius: Me too faced same type of issue. Fixed by your answer thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Tanks. i have face an issue with it  and now got the solution

Comment: Issue with free FBlike extension from magento marketplace (1.0.6) for Magento 2.  Same error , add 
<tab id="swissup" translate="label" sortOrder="200">
            <label>Swissup</label>
        </tab>
in system.xml

Comment: @Marius: Thanks for the answer, Worked for me.